# Java regular expression for string containing at least one alphanumeric character, in any location

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a terse Java regular expression that can be used as an argument to the `String.matches(…)` method and it returns true if the string contains at least one alphanumeric character, **in any location**.  I have tried a few things but nothing seems to work.  As an example, I tried the following regex:

`*[a-zA-Z0-9]+*`

However, I get the following run-time exception:

```
Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
*[a-zA-Z0-9]+*
^
```

Comment: This regex does not work for my situation.  For example, "@xyz" should evaluate to true, but it evaluates to false with the suggested regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String.matches` method attempts to match the entire string to the regular expression. So an expression that matches any string with an alphanumeric in it would be: `".*\\w.*"` Note that `\w` includes the underscore character so if you don't want that included then stick with your more explicit pattern.

Alternatively you could use `Pattern.find` to just find `"\\w"` anywhere in your string.

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk ('*') is not the symbol for matching any character, period ('.') is.

You need to change your regex to `.[a-zA-Z0-9]+.`

The asterisk is used to specify the count of the matched pattern:

`[0-9]+` means **at least one digit**

`[0-9]*` means **none, one ore more digits**